# Project Euler #50, prime sums not correct?

Tags: racket, primes

> The prime 41, can be written as the sum of six consecutive primes:
>
> 41 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 This is the longest sum of consecutive
>   primes that adds to a prime below one-hundred.
>
> The longest sum of consecutive primes below one-thousand that adds to
>   a prime, contains 21 terms, and is equal to 953.
>
> Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most
>   consecutive primes?

I'm using Racket (a dialect of scheme) for this example, but this should be language agnostic. In the question, it states that the sum of the first 21 consecutive primes is 953. So, I went to test this out (I had already written my code for this problem and it was working incorrectly).

```
> (define primes (filter prime? (range 2 10000)))
> (apply + (take primes 6)) ; This is 41: Good so far!
> ; This is where it gets odd.
> (apply + (take primes 21)) ; This is 712. And, after further experimentation, there is amount of summed primes that is 953.
> (apply + (take primes 23)) ; This is 874.
> (apply + (take primes 24)) ; This is 963.
```

Is there something I'm missing about the question?

Comment: The question talks about consecutive primes, are you summing consecutive primes or any primes?

Comment: The sum of the first `m` primes where `m` is an odd number cannot be prime because the sum is always an even number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the question wrong.  The sum must also be a prime, which 963 is not (107 * 9, for example).

Comment: @DarthGizka Wups.  Fixed answer.

Comment: now your answer is correct, and it being accepted is OK. :) note, if you'd say "my answer is wrong" it'd cause all kinds of paradoxes, being accepted. by saying "_old_ answer _was_ wrong" you avoid all that... :)  happy travels!

Answer (score 3):

[Euler #50](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=50) asks for sums of consecutive primes, which need not necessarily begin with the first prime. The fact that the shown example starts with the first prime is incidental (although it is no accident that the winning sequence starts with at a *small* prime).

```
953 =  7 + 11 + 13 + 17 + 19 + 23 + 29 
    + 31 + 37 + 41 + 43 + 47 + 53 + 59 
    + 61 + 67 + 71 + 73 + 79 + 83 + 89
```

That's 21 terms. There is no mistake in the problem description - the term 'first' does not appear anywhere in the text.